# How to declare field inside Enum in Java?

Tags: java, enums

I want to declare static(or not static) variable inside Enum. I need this because I want to associate enum values with some strings. But i Don't want to hardcode this strings. I want to use my application-wide class with String constants.
I.e. I want to write like this inside `enum` declaraton, but there compile time error:

```
public enum MyEnum {   
        private static final AppConstants CONSTANTS = AppConstants.getInstance();

        ONE(CONSTANTS.one()),
        TWO(CONSTANTS.two());
}
```

How I can put in enum a field?

Comment: Why does you AppConstants have a get Instance? Can it not be an `enum` as well with one instance?

Comment: in fact I use GWT, and there `private  AppMessages MESSAGES = (AppMessages) GWT.create(AppMessages.class);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's one of the limitations, the enum values must be specified **first** but you can always refer to the same singelton in every instantiation...

```
enum MyEnum {

    ONE(Test.getInstance().one()),
    TWO(Test.getInstance().two());

    public final String val;

    MyEnum(String val) { this.val = val; }
}
```

Example that outputs "hello":

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(MyEnum.ONE.val);
    }

    public String one() {
        return "hello";
    }
    public String two() {
        return "world" ;
    }

    static Test instance;
    public synchronized static Test getInstance() {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new Test();
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit hacky. But you'll have to change your `AppConstants` class a bit.

```
public enum MyEnum {   
    ONE(getConstant("one")),
    TWO(getConstant("one"));

    private static final AppConstants CONSTANTS = AppConstants.getInstance();

    private static String getConstant(String key) {
        // You can use a map inside the AppConstants or you can 
        // invoke the right method using reflection. Up to you.
        return CONSTANTS.get(key);
    }

    private MyEnum(String value) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The enum constants need to be the first elements in the Enumeration

```
public enum MyEnum {   

    ONE,TWO;
    private static final AppConstants CONSTANTS = AppConstants.getInstance();

    @Override 
public String toString() {
       if(this==ONE){
           return CONSTANTS.one();
       } else if(this==TWO){
           return CONSTANTS.two();
       }
    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: -1, no you cannot because: `Cannot reference a field before it is defined`!

Comment: thanks, but now filed CONSTANTS is not visible for enums constants :)

Comment: @HardikMishra He said nothing about `toString` he wants to associate enum values with strings.

Comment: Actually , I thought it  as its mentioned in question "I need this because I want to associate enum values with some strings. But i Don't want to hardcode this strings"

Comment: -1 This doesn't solve the problem as asked at all. First of all, instead of looking each constant up *once*, they have to be looked up every time they are needed, which could be a performance issue. Second, the strings could vary over time, since the contents of the map might change. The accepted answer is the right one.